# Use Gram-Schmidt Process to make vectors orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v = (4,2,-4)$ and w = $(-2,3,6)$. Check that the vector
   $s= w - \frac{v \cdot w}{v \cdot v}v$ is orthogonal to $v$.

I have tried this several times and have not gotten an answer that makes sense. 
I need a sanity check. Thanks.

Comment: what did you get for $s?$

Comment: 1. Compute s. 2. Compute $s \cdot v$. 3. Verify that step 2 gave 0.

Comment: I have. It doesn't come out to 0.

Comment: Please show your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(-2,3,6)-\frac{(4,2,-4)\cdot(-2,3,6)}{||(4,2,-4)||^2}(4,2,-4)=(-2,3,6)-\frac1{36}\cdot(-26)(4,2,-4)=$$

$$(-2,3,6)+\left(\frac{52}{18}\;,\;\frac{26}{18}\;,\;-\frac{52}{18}\right)=\left(\frac{16}{18}\;,\;\frac{80}{18}\;,\;\frac{56}{18}\right)$$

And now

$$\left(\frac{16}{18}\;,\;\frac{80}{18}\;,\;\frac{56}{18}\right)\cdot(4,2,-4)=\frac{64+160-224}{18}=0$$

Comment: i think it would help OP if they do some work towards a solution.

Comment: He showed the correct way to do it. Obviously he was making some arithmetical, or other, mistake somewhere. Questions like this, imo, don't leave much space to hints and stuff.